# Replace a string character by only using charAt()

Tags: java, replace, char, charat

I'm new to Java and OOP. I'm currently studying for a class test and have the following question:

My task is to replace some characters in a given sentence by only using the `length()` and `charAt()` methods.

I was given the sentence:

> "This is the letter i!"

this method:

```
public static String replaceCharacter(String w, char b, String v) { 
}
```

and the result should look like this:

> "Theasts easts the letter east"

This is my starting point. I have no idea how to solve this one without using `substring()` method. Hope somebody can help me and give some explanation.

Comment: I suggest you try using charAt or search for one of the millions of examples available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just loop through the `String` and if the `charAt(i)` is equal to your specific `char`, then append the replacement, otherwise append the `charAt(i)`

```
public static String replaceCharacter(String w, char b, String v) {
    String result = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < w.length(); i++) {
        if (w.charAt(i) == b) {
            result += v;
        } else {
            result += w.charAt(i);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

**[Demo](https://ideone.com/HxEkyj)**

Comment: Thanks @notyou! It perfectly works and I guess I understand the concept!

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to remember that a String is essentially just an array of characters and if we want to change elements in an array, we can do that by using loops.

I'll assume that:

```
String w = "This is the letter i!";
char b = 'i';
String v = "east";
```

The method then is:

```
public static String replaceCharacter(String w, char b, String v) { 
    for (int i = 0; i < w.length(); i++) {
        if (w.charAt(i) != b) {
            // if the character is not 'i', we don't want to replace it
        } else {
            // otherwise, we want to replace it by "east"
        }
    }
}
```

Figuring out what code should go in the if and else block should be easy. Good luck!